# How to create a virtual coin system in my game using Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to integrate in my Flutter app a credit system in which every user has his own balance of virtual coin, and of course they can earn coin while improving in the game. What are the main services should I use to enable this feature? Using Firestore Collections is enough?

Comment: You could have a collection for coins - for each user when they earn the coins you can increment their coins. 

I see it more of virtual counter you need to keep track for each user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I previously have done something like this using Firestore Collections, and store credit value for each user is enough. For each user, just add a new field 'credit' and set the balance for each user. You can get, add or subtract the value after.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6InUw.png)